# I am getting a FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION when trying to insert a PriceBookEntry in the Standard Pricebook. Could anyone help me?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am getting a FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION when trying to insert a PriceBookEntry in the Standard Pricebook. Could anyone help me?

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
private class test_checkAvailability 
{

    @isTest static void testAvailability() 
    {
        //Inserción de datos de testeo.
        Pricebook2 standardPB = [select id, Name from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];
        Product2 testProduct = new Product2(Name = 'Test Product', IsActive = True);
        insert testProduct;
        PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = standardPB.Id, Product2Id = testProduct.Id, UnitPrice = 35, IsActive = true);
        insert standardPrice;
        Account testAccount = new Account(Name ='Test Account');
        insert testAccount;
        Order testOrder = new Order(AccountId = testAccount.Id);
        insert testOrder;

        Test.startTest();
        OrderItem testOrderItem = new OrderItem (OrderId = testOrder.Id, PricebookEntryId = standardPrice.Id, Quantity = 3);
        insert testOrderItem;
        Test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Test.getStandardPricebookId()` get the standard pricebook id as follows in test classes.

```
Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
```

And then, no need to use `SeeAllData= true`.

Refer [Create Price Book Entries in Apex Tests](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_apex_price_books_in_tests.htm)

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
private class test_checkAvailability 
{

    @isTest static void testAvailability() 
    {
        //Inserción de datos de testeo.
        Pricebook2 standardPB = [select id, Name from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];

        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();


        Product2 testProduct = new Product2(Name = 'Test Product', IsActive = True);
        insert testProduct;

        PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = testProduct.Id, UnitPrice = 35, IsActive = true);
        insert standardPrice;
        Account testAccount = new Account(Name ='Test Account');
        insert testAccount;
        Order testOrder = new Order(AccountId = testAccount.Id);
        insert testOrder;

        Test.startTest();
        OrderItem testOrderItem = new OrderItem (OrderId = testOrder.Id, PricebookEntryId = standardPrice.Id, Quantity = 3);
        insert testOrderItem;
        Test.stopTest();

    }

}
```